# Opening a UIView from another UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a UIViewController with a button that opens a Modal/Popup (XIB)

I use this code for that:

```
let aView: myView1 = UINib(nibname: "AView", bundle : nil).instantitate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! myView1
aView.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubView(aView)
```

The Modal contains a button that should open a Form (another XIB)

I use this code for that:

```
let bView: myView2 = UINib(nibname: "BView", bundle : nil).instantitate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! myView2
bView.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubView(bView)
```

But I get a compile time error, saying:

> Value of type 'AView' has no member 'view'

When I changed the code from:

```
self.view.addSubview(bView)
```

to:

```
self.addSubview(bView)
```

I get a runtime error when using above line in UIView:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.

If I relocate the above line to UIViewController, I get a different error:

> Can't add self as subview

Is there some other way that works to open a UIView from another UIView, without going back or making changes to the UIViewController?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are doing this on `UIView`s and not using full `UIViewController`s for your modals and showing them using `present(viewController:animated:completion:)` method?

Comment: i wrote the UIView using XIB, that is the only reason. Now i rewrote the whole thing using Storyboard and UIViewController, i face no problem as specified earlier.

btw, the coding-compliant issue was due to broken outlet reference.

Comment: You can have view controllers in xibs too.

Answer (score 0):

First i suggest change class name from `myView1` to `MyView1`, same to `myView2`. Then set your nib files `file's owner` from interface builder to `MyView1` and `MyView1`.

Change this `withOwner: self` to `nil` in below call:

```
let aView:myView1 = UINib(nibname: "AView", bundle : nil).instantitate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! myView1
```

OR

You might need to remove `file's owner` from interface builder.